# How to make multiple constructors in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to use library which is in Java and it has alot of errors so I'm trying to change it to Kotlin. And AndroidStudio is not converting Java to Kotlin properly so I have to do it function by function and check it manually. But these 3 constructors gives error:

Error: `None of these following functions can be called with the arguments supplied`

Java:

```
public class CountryCodePicker extends RelativeLayout
...

        public CountryCodePicker(Context context) {
        super(context);
        if (!isInEditMode()) init(null);
      }

      public CountryCodePicker(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        if (!isInEditMode()) init(attrs);
      }

      public CountryCodePicker(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        if (!isInEditMode()) init(attrs);
      }
```

Kotlin:

```
class CountryCodePicker: RelativeLayout
...

constructor(context: Context): this{
        super(context)
        if (!isInEditMode) init(null)
    }

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet): this{
        super(context, attrs)
        if (!isInEditMode) init(attrs)
    }

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyleAttr: Int): this{
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)
        if (!isInEditMode) init(attrs)
    }
```

Comment: You didn't show us how you call this code (e.g. it's important whether any of the arguments could be `null`)?

Comment: In Java code it is called like this: CountryCodePicker ccp=view.findViewById(R.id.ccp);

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
class CountryCodePicker: RelativeLayout {

constructor(context: Context) : super(context) {
    if (!isInEditMode) init(null)
}

constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet): super(context, attrs){
    if (!isInEditMode) init(attrs)
}

constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyleAttr: Int): super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
    if (!isInEditMode) init(attrs)
}


}
```

Comment: Please don't use this! Check my answer for a better approach with `JvmOverloads`.

Answer (score 4):

You should use `JvmOverloads` for this:

```kotlin
class CountryCodePicker @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : RelativeLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
    init {
        if (!isInEditMode()) {
            init(attrs) // or better inline the function body
        }
    }
}
```

The `JvmOverloads` will create the 3 constructors with the default values as defined. That is the behavior you would expect and makes the code cleaner.